# Suggestions on the best way to migrate to a new server

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, migration

I have an OLD server (Windows server 2012 R2) and a NEW server (Windows server 2022).

Old server is a bare-metal Domain Controller Server and the New server is a VM.  I am planning on migrating to the New Sever.

OLD SERVER

Windows Server 2012 R2
Domain functional level: Windows Server 2012 R2
Domain functional level: Windows Server 2012 R2

What is the best way to move forward with regards to the Domain Controller Role.

Option 1: Start from scratch on the New server with New Domain (install a new DC role and recreate all the users/computers/GPO etc).

Option 2: Install and Promote the New Server as Domain Controller in the existing Domain and then Demote the Old server and transfer/move/migrate the FSMO roles to the New Server.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My opinion is Option 2 is the most obvious way to go about it. It's been years since I've dealt with this stuff though.

Comment: It depends. Usually option 2, but if you have other goals like moving from `.local` naming to the recommended `ad.example.com` naming, you might go with option 1.

Comment: You should still have at least 2 domain controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new domain *may* be the right course of action in certain very specific cases, otherwise, for production environments and the vast majority of instances, doing the install and promote method is correct.

You will need to define what your actual use case is, including specifics, and IF there are reasons that demand creating a new domain then you'd choose option 1, but if there aren't, the right thing to do is option 2.